# Replication Controller Not Found

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform and Kubernetes. I've been following [this](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/cross-region-http-services-container-engine) tutorial and stuck with the following command:

`kubectl expose rc my-nginx --target-port=80 --type=NodePort`

When in try to expose the RC it would print:

`Error from server (NotFound): replicationcontrollers "my-nginx" not found`

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following commands to create nginx pod and expose it as a service, as mentioned [in this article](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer):

**Create nginx pod:**

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80
```

**Expose nginx as a service:**

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --target-port=80 --type=NodePort
```